# AngularJS Convert JSON string to object data.d.results[]

Tags: json, angularjs

I am returning a string of serialized data from a web service.
I apply the two following:

```
         data= JSON.parse(data);
         data= angular.fromJson(data);
```

I end up with the following

```
data.Campus
data.StudentNumber
data.Firstname
```

what it needs to be is

```
data.d.results[0].Campus
data.d.results[0].StudentNumber
data.d.results[0].FirstName
```

How is this done.
Thanks
Joe

Comment: why not just goodData = data.d.results[0] and then goodData.Campus etc? unless you controll the web service data so you should form a better shaped json

Answer (score 0):

If you have json and want return string, you can use

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting a response from your service as a stringified JSON. You want to store that as object data as the first element of an array in data.d.results? If I understand correct (though I'm not sure why you're saving it this way) alls you need is the below. If I misunderstand let me know in a comment and I'll try to assist.

```
data.d.results[0] = JSON.parse(response);
```